# Null Check operator used on null value in Dart Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Null check operator on null value error in Dart flutter which is caused by User user instance variable. Please help how to run this code to get value from firebase. Dummy user variables working fine till now.
Code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import '../models/user.dart';
import '../services/database/users_database_services.dart';

class UserController extends GetxController {
  String userID = '';
  bool previouslyLoggedIn = false;
  UserDBService userDBService = UserDBService();

  User? user;
  setUser(String userID, String name, String phone, String email, int usercnic,
      String profilePictureLink) {
    this.userID = userID;
    user = User(
      email: email,
      name: name,
      phone: phone,
      userID: userID,
      usercnic: usercnic,
      profilePictureLink: profilePictureLink,
    );
  }

  updateDbUser() async {
    bool isSuccess = await userDBService.addUser(userID, user!.name,
        user!.phone, user!.email, user!.usercnic, user!.profilePictureLink);

    if (isSuccess) {
      Get.snackbar(
        "success",
        "User details updated successfully",
        snackPosition: SnackPosition.BOTTOM,
      );
    } else {
      Get.snackbar(
        "error",
        "User details not updated successfully",
        snackPosition: SnackPosition.BOTTOM,
        backgroundColor: Colors.red,
        colorText: Colors.white,
        duration: const Duration(seconds: 2),
      );
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you please add your error log here?

Comment: Are you sure you always call `setUser` before `updateDbUser()`? The error is about your calling `user!` which is an enforced cast from a nullable (`User?`) to non-nullable (`User`) type. The cast will put a runtime check which makes sure your application crashes in case `user` ends up being `null` even if you have promised that would not be the case.

Answer (score 1):

The null check operator `!` will treat the nullable value in front of it, a variable that may or may not be null, as non-nullable. In your case, this is `user` inside `updateDbUser`.

As mentioned in the comments, it is likely caused by calling `updateDbUser` before the `user` field is set. Since you already have a way to display failed updates, I would suggest simply setting `isSuccess` to false if there is no user:

```dart
updateDbUser() async {
  bool isSuccess = user != null && await userDBService.addUser(...);
  
  ...
}
```

This should ensure that user is not null, and if it is, it will simply set `isSuccess` to false and show you the red banner. Where possible, it is advisable to avoid the null check operator `!`, as it leads you to runtime exceptions/errors.

Answer (score 0):

Add null value condition in adding user like below  or you can check if user is not empty

```
bool isSuccess = await userDBService.addUser(userID, user?.name ?? "",
    user?.phone ?? "", user?.email ?? "", user?.usercnic ?? 0, user?.profilePictureLink ?? "");
```

or

```
bool isSuccess = false;

if(user!= null)
{
   isSucess = await userDBService.addUser(userID, user!.name,
               user!.phone, user!.email, user!.usercnic, user!.profilePictureLink);
}
```

Comment: Eh so if `user` ends up being `null` you want to create an empty row in the database?

Comment: That's also a solution like adding a user with a null check @julemand101

Comment: My question was meant to be about your code. You can see that if `user` are `null`, every field are being replaced to empty strings or `0` (expect for `userID`). That would rarely be something you actually want to happen.

Comment: Please check updated one @julemand101

Comment: You second example does not make much sense since we know that all the fields on a `User` are not `null` if you check the code from the question. So no need for the usage of `??` operator. Instead, I would add a local `_user` variable and check that against `null` since it would then promote the variable to a non-nullable type.

Answer (score 0):

your user data is null, check user data before update as below:

```
updateDbUser() async {
 bool isSuccess=false;
 if(user!=null){
isSuccess = await userDBService.addUser(userID, user!.name,
    user!.phone, user!.email, user!.usercnic, user!.profilePictureLink);
 }
if (isSuccess) {
  Get.snackbar(
    "success",
    "User details updated successfully",
    snackPosition: SnackPosition.BOTTOM,
  );
} else {
  Get.snackbar(
    "error",
    "User details not updated successfully",
    snackPosition: SnackPosition.BOTTOM,
    backgroundColor: Colors.red,
    colorText: Colors.white,
    duration: const Duration(seconds: 2),
  );
}
}
```